# Delete repeated fields in an R data.frame

Tags: r, alteryx

I'm very new on R and I need your help to do something that Until now i can't do:

I have a data frame that could have a random number of columns, I need to mantain in each column of the data frame only the unique values, but this have to be done independent of the other columns:

For example, if have the below data frame:

```
 Column_A   Column_B    Column_C
    A               1           A1  
    A               2           A2
    B               1           A3
    B               2           A4
    C               3           A5
    C               4           A6
```

The output for this, after the code must be:

```
Column_A    Column_B    Column_C
A               1           A1
B               2           A2
C               3           A3
                4           A4
                            A5
                            A6
```

I've tried with `ds <- unique(ds)` but it only will leave the unique relations between all the columns.

I will really apreciate any help or orientation you could gave me.

Thanks in advance.

**Data**

```
`> str(df)
'data.frame':   6 obs. of  3 variables:
 $ A: chr  "A" "B" "C" "A" ...
 $ B: num  1 2 1 2 3 4
 $ C: chr  "A1" "A2" "A3" "A4" ...`
```

**Loop**

```
`i <- 1`
`while (i < ncol(df)){
+  df[i] <-  lapply(df, function(x) {
+           x[duplicated(x)] <- ''
+           c(x[x!=''], x[x==''])})
+ i <- i+1
+}`
```

Comment: What are you planning to do with your desired output? I almost never need or want ragged arrays as columns; in particular, for `data.frame` each column must have the same length. You could pad out the columns with spaces or NAs, but what is the point?

Comment: the output will be formated and used to generate dinamyc queries that I use in an alteryx module.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there are 'factor' columns, it is better to convert it to `character` or include `''` as one of the levels of the `factor` column.  Here, I am changing the `factor` columns to `character` first.

```
 indx <- sapply(df1, is.factor)
 df1[indx] <- lapply(df1[indx], as.character)
```

Loop the columns with `lapply`, replace the `duplicated` elements with `''`, arrange the elements so that the empty strings will be at the end (`c(x[x=''],x==''])`)

```
 df1[] <-  lapply(df1, function(x) {
           x[duplicated(x)] <- ''
           c(x[x!=''], x[x==''])})
 df1
 #   Column_A Column_B Column_C
 #1        A        1       A1
 #2        B        2       A2
 #3        C        3       A3
 #4                 4       A4
 #5                         A5
 #6                         A6
```

Or another option would be to use `match`

```
df1[] <- lapply(df1, function(x) c(x[match(unique(x),x)],
               rep('', length(x)-length(unique(x)))))
```

NOTE: Using `''` will change the numeric column classes to 'character/factor' class.  It may be better to replace with `NA` which can be easily deleted also with custom functions `is.na/na.omit/complete.cases` etc..

#### data

```
 df1 <- structure(list(Column_A = structure(c(1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L), 
 .Label = c("A", 
 "B", "C"), class = "factor"), Column_B = c(1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 
 4L), Column_C = structure(1:6, .Label = c("A1", "A2", "A3", "A4", 
 "A5", "A6"), class = "factor")), .Names = c("Column_A", "Column_B", 
 "Column_C"), row.names = c(NA, -6L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Doing this I get som errors:

1: In `[<-.factor`(`*tmp*`, duplicated(x), value = "")

2: In `[<-.factor`(`*tmp*`, duplicated(x), value = "") :

3: In `[<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, , value = list(A = c(1L, NA, 2L, NA,  :

Comment: @SergioDonosoSoto  It is better to change the factor columns to character as in the updated post.  Also, you can do this automatically by using `stringsAsFactors=FALSE` in the `read.csv/read.table`

Comment: Hi, I was lookin my data and after apply match or the first formula, happens that when I loop this formula trough my columns, the second formula get the data of the first column, nad i don't know why:

for example my `column_A` (with letters) will replace with `A, B, C` the `column_B` (that previously had numbers) to `A, B, C` too! this will be for **every** column exept the last one, for the loop I'm doing:

`i <- 1`
`while (i < ncol(df)){
+ df[i] <- lapply(df, function(x) {
+ x[duplicated(x)] <- ''
+ c(x[x!=''], x[x==''])})
+ i <- i + 1
+ }`

Comment: @SergioDonosoSoto  I am not sure what is happening without a `dput` example.  Could you update the post with the dput output of the first 6 rows.  Based on the example you showed, I am getting the correct output

Comment: @SergioDonosoSoto  I updated the post with the data I used.  Here, the 2nd column is not factor while the 1st and 3rd are factors.  You can check the class of your dataset with `str(yourdata)`

Comment: I've updated the post with the data and the loop, the data frame is a collection of vectors (just for testing purposes)

Comment: @smdonosos  Thanks for the update and glad that you were able to find the error.